# Loop through a single node

Tags: php, for-loop, xml-parsing

The URL link below returns an XML with a single node:

```
http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?DistributorKey=201201100935&CommandName=QueryProducts&CommandParameters=<parameters>
<row><param>PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST</param><value>ACCOMM</value></row>
</parameters>
```

I intend to loop through the response and extract some attributes such as (product_name, product_description).
My php code does not return any value when i run the program.
Please see code below:

```
<?php

$url = file_get_contents("http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?DistributorKey=201201100935&CommandName=QueryProducts&CommandParameters=<parameters>
<row><param>PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST</param><value>ACCOMM</value></row>
</parameters>");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);

foreach ($xml->item as $entry) {
echo $entry->product_name;
echo $entry->product_description;
}

?>
```

Please what am I doing wrongly?
Many thanks

Comment: When I request that URL, I get an XML with one tag `<string>` that holds some raw data that could be XML. (XML wrapped in XML? seriously? who designed this thing?)

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Please copy the url into your browser and you will be able to understand my question better: "http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?DistributorKey=201201100935&CommandName=QueryProducts&CommandParameters=<parameters>
<row><param>PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST</param><value>ACCOMM</value></row>
</parameters>"

Comment: @BartFriederichs; it is the API response of a web service (Tourism) which I am analysing. What can I do to rectify it?

Comment: contact the developer of the web service and request to implement his XML interface properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML that you've got from the service is not valid. 
In fact, you can make it valid, but it will make your script work slower. 
But you can if you don't have any choice

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?DistributorKey=201201100935&CommandName=QueryProducts&CommandParameters=<parameters><row><param>PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST</param><value>ACCOMM</value></row></parameters>");

$url = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $url);
$url = str_replace('<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/soap/AustralianTourismWebService">', '', $url);
$url = str_replace('</string>', '', $url);
$url = str_replace('utf-16', 'utf-8', $url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string(trim(html_entity_decode($url)), 'SimpleXMLElement');

foreach ($xml->product_distribution as $entry) {
    echo "Product name: " . $entry->product_record->product_name . "<br />";
    echo "Product description:" . $entry->product_record->product_description . "<br />";
}
```